# Como mudar a cor de um link após ter sido acessado e ficar salvo no site sem apagar após clicar F5

Tags: php, javascript, css, html5

Como faço para trocar a cor do link que esta dentro da minha tabela. Esse link e utilizado para baixar um arquivo de acordo com o ID dele. Eu queria que por padrão ficasse vermelho e quando a pessoa clicar para baixar ele ficasse em verde porem que realmente ficasse salvo no site e se a pessoa logar no sistema de novo não saísse.

```
<div style=" padding-bottom: 50px;" class="p-4">
      <h3>Afastamento Médico</h3>
        <table id="id_da_tabela" class="table table-hover" >

    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Arquivo</th>
        <th>size</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>CPF</th>
         <th>Nome</th>
         <th>Cargo</th>
         <th>D.Inicio</th>
         <th>D. Final</th>
         <th>Data do Envio</th>
        <th>Download</th>
        <th>Aprovar</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($files as $file): ?>
        <tr>
          <td data-title="ID"><?php echo $file['ID']; ?>
          </td>
          <td data-title="Arquivo"><?php echo $file['PATH']; ?></td>
          <td data-title="size (in mb)"><?php echo floor($file['size'] / 1000) . ' KB'; ?></td>
          <td data-title="Matricula"><?php echo $file['MATRICULA']; ?></td>
          <td data-title="pis"><?php echo $file['PIS']; ?></td>
          <td data-title="Nome"><?php echo $file['NOME']; ?></td>
          <td data-title="Cargo"><?php echo $file['SETOR']; ?></td>
          <td data-title="datainicio"><?php echo $file['DATAINICIO']; ?></td>
          <td data-title="datafinal"><?php echo $file['DATAFINAL']; ?></td>
          <td data-title="Data"><?php echo $file['DATA_UPLOAD']; ?></td>
          <td data-title="Download"><a href="downloads.php?file_id=<?php echo $file['ID'] ?>">Download</a></td>
          <td><button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button" name="button"><a  style="color: #fff" href="aprovar_att.php?file_id=<?php echo $file['ID'] ?>">ACEITAR</a></button></td>
            <td> <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" type="button" name="button"><a  style="color: #fff"  href="reprovar_att.php?file_id=<?php echo $file['ID'] ?>">REJEITAR</a></td>
              
             </tr>
         <?php
        endforeach;
        ?>
        
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Observação: O link seria o [inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ut4p.png)">Download

Answer (score -4):

```
<style>
a:visited {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Ola amigo eu fiz isso e nao deu certo! acredito que como o dado que preenche a coluna vem pelo um ID do php teria que ser algo em java script